# Get API key and auth domain from google_identity_platform_config

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I need to set env variables for Firebase authentication (API key and auth domain) for a web app that is deployed using Terraform.

This information can be found in the Google Cloud Console, by going to "Identity Platform" and clicking the "Application Setup Details" button.

However, as I've setup the Identity Platform using Terraform, it seems like I should be able to get the key values from there rather than manually entering the details.

Is it there somewhere? I've searched the documentation back and forth in vain.

Note that I do not have a Firebase project: I only use Identity Platform.

Comment: Did you find a way to get the API key? I'm at the same point.

Comment: unfortunately not